# An Anaconda environment won't activate?

Tags: anaconda, python-3.8

I'm on a mac, and I'm trying to download a software called DLITE (which can be found here https://github.com/AllenCellModeling/DLITE). However, the instructions provided don't work I'm using Anaconda, and when I try and activate the environment that I've created, I get the following error message :

conda init dlite

ArgumentError: Invalid shells:

- dlite

Currently available shells are:

- bash
- fish
- powershell
- tcsh
- xonsh
- zsh

I haven't used Anaconda or python much before, and I have no idea what to do to fix this, although I've tried a few things.

Comment: As far as I know, `conda init` activates the `conda` command for your terminal - therefore, I believe `conda init` does not received any argument (such as `dlite`). To create an environment, I would follow [anaconda's tutorial](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#creating-an-environment-with-commands).

Answer (score 0):

```
$ conda create --name dlite python=3.7
$ conda activate dlite
```

The command above will create the environment (as written in the `dlite` tutorial.

```
$ git clone https://github.com/AllenCellModeling/DLITE.git
$ cd DLITE
$ pip install -e .[all]
```

This will install the needed packages.

Hope this helped.

Comment: I've tried following exactly what they say; but when I try to enter "conda activate dlite", I get the following error message : CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda activate'.
To initialize your shell, run

    $ conda init <SHELL_NAME>

And when I try this I get : conda init dlite

ArgumentError: Invalid shells: 
  - dlite

Comment: Correction - looking at the environments, it seems that I've managed to activate DLITE, but the last step, "pip install -e .[all]", doesn't seem to work : "  zsh:1: no matches found: .[all]  ". And if I keep going, python won't even open anymore and I don't know why

Comment: Try `conda init` and then `conda activate dlite` while using your default terminal. The `<SHELL_NAME>` is not your environment name.